# Windows 8 app fullscreen webview C#

Tags: c#, windows, windows-8, webview

I'm making a simple WebView app for windows 8 but there's a problem the size of the WebView is just about 2/3 of the screen and I want it to be full screen. In the Design Mode of VS I've set it to fullscreen.

Comment: care to share the code?

Comment: Oh I forgot but now I've already solved it.

Comment: Please post your answer as an actual answer because Stackoverflow is not a forum!

Comment: I wanted but it said I don't have enough reputation points and I have to wait 24h :(

Answer (score 0):

you give hard code Height="768" Width="1366" but when we change the resolution it's never work. so you can also use "Window.Current.Bounds.Height" to get height of window same you can use for width.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it myself by just deleting the automaticly generated part of the code (`HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="768" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1366"`) now it's fullscreen :)

Answer (score 0):

Better this, remove width and height

```
<WebView HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Double check for a margin value set by default.  My Win10 Universal App markup looks like this:

```
<WebView HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
```